# C# / .NET Convert string to a usable type that references a DLL class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a set of code that takes in a value (a string) that contains the exact name of a class that I need to reference. The class to be referenced is in a separate DLL file (I already put the `using lib_vxmanager;` for the DLL). I simply need to get the string to a proper type that can be used to do something like this:

```
Classname class = new Classname();
```

Code sample:

```
public void Classreference(string reference_name)
{
    string Classname = reference_name.Split('{','}')[0]; //This is the classname
    //Convert name to type here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`Activator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance("Your assembly name", "Your class name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Assembly.CreateInstance` and `Activator.CreateInstance`.